# how do I properly use the result of argmin to slice out an array of the minimums?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm looking to slice out the minimum value along the first axis of an array.
For example, in the code below, I want to print out `np.array([13, 0, 12, 3])`.
However, the slicing isn't behaving as I would think it does.
(I do need the argmin array later and don't want to just use `np.min(g, axis=1)`)

```
import numpy as np
g = np.array([[13, 23, 14], [12, 23, 0], [39, 12, 92], [19, 4, 3]])
min_ = np.argmin(g, axis=1)
print(g[:, min_])
```

What is happening here?
Why is my result from the code

```
[[13 14 23 14]
 [12  0 23  0]
 [39 92 12 92]
 [19  3  4  3]]
```

Other details:
Python 3.10.2
Numpy 1.22.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use `np.argmin`, you can try this:

**For more explanation :** from `min_` you have `array([0, 2, 1, 2])`  but for accessing to array you need `((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 2, 1, 2))` for this reason you can use `range`.

```
min_ = np.argmin(g, axis=1)
g[range(len(min_)), min_] # like as np.min(g ,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([13,  0, 12,  3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing the first, third, second, and third columns of the `g` array, in that order.

```
>>> np.argmin(g, axis=1)
array([0, 2, 1, 2])  # first, third, second, third
```

If you want to get the minimum value of each row, use `np.min`:

```
>>> np.min(g, axis=1)
array([13,  0, 12,  3])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `g[:, min_]`, you're saying: "give me **all of the rows** (shorthand `:`) for **columns at indices** `min_` (namely `0, 2, 1, 2`)".

What you wanted to say was: "give me the values at **these rows and these columns**" - in other words, you're missing the corresponding **row indices** to match the column indices in `min_`.

Since your desired row indices are simply a range of numbers from `0` to `g.shape[0] - 1`, you could technically write it as:

```
print(g[range(g.shape[0]), min_])
# output: [13  0 12  3]
```

But @richardec's solution is better overall if your goal is to extract the row-wise min value.